# OpenTelemetry Swift - how to send **logs** to an OpenTelemetry Collector?

Tags: ios, swift, logging, open-telemetry, open-telemetry-collector

I'm making an iPhone app and want to use an OpenTelemetry Collector on my server to collect Metrics, Traces and Logs. I've implemented Metrics and Traces using [this package](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-swift), and it works just fine!

The GitHub page stays that "Logs are considered beta quality", and I can see that there are some parts of the log system implemented in the package.

I've tried out the following code, but I seem to be missing something - it doesn't seem to send anything:

```
let instrumentationScopeName = "TestInstrumentationScopeName" //Don't know what to put here....

let loggerProvider = LoggerProviderSdk()

OpenTelemetry.registerLoggerProvider(loggerProvider: loggerProvider)

let logger = loggerProvider.get(instrumentationScopeName: instrumentationScopeName)

var logRecordBuilder = logger.logRecordBuilder()

var attributes: [String: AttributeValue] = [:]
attributes["TestAttributeA"] = AttributeValue("TestAttributeValueA")
attributes["TestAttributeB"] = AttributeValue("TestAttributeValueB")
attributes["TestAttributeC"] = AttributeValue("TestAttributeValueC")

logRecordBuilder = logRecordBuilder.setAttributes(attributes)
logRecordBuilder = logRecordBuilder.setBody("LogBody")
logRecordBuilder = logRecordBuilder.setObservedTimestamp(Date.now)
logRecordBuilder = logRecordBuilder.setSeverity(Severity.debug3)

logRecordBuilder.emit()


var eventBuilder = logger.eventBuilder(name: "asdf")
eventBuilder = eventBuilder.setAttributes(attributes)
eventBuilder = eventBuilder.setBody("LogBody")
eventBuilder = eventBuilder.setObservedTimestamp(Date.now)
eventBuilder = eventBuilder.setSeverity(Severity.debug3)

eventBuilder.emit()
```

I'm running the OpenTelemetry collector locally on macOS with [this config](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector/blob/main/examples/local/otel-config.yaml) - but I'm trying to add logs to the service->pipeines like this:

```
    logs:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [memory_limiter, batch]
      exporters: [logging]
```

I'm testing from xCode's iPhone simulator.

I've tried a network monitor, and as far as I can see, nothing gets sent. It gives plenty of output, when Traces and Metrics are sent. And they are also picked up by the collector.

When calling the method, I get the following log: `` Events cannot be emitted from Logger without an event domain. Use `LoggerBuilder.setEventDomain(_ domain: String) when obtaining a Logger. ``

I am stuck here.

Have anyone successfully sent a log from OpenTelemetry Swift to an OpenTelemetry Collector? Any help would be very valued! Especially code-examples! :-)

(If it's impossible to do, workarounds would also be very appreciated. I've heard that you could send a single-Span Trace the log-text in it as a workaround - but how do you distinguish the logging-Traces from the normal Traces and channel only them into the logs-pipeline in the OpenTelemetry Collector?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This example](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-swift/blob/main/Examples/Logs%20Sample/main.swift) works!

Thanks a lot to **bryce-b**!

The eventProvider in the example can be put to use like this:

```
var logRecordBuilder = eventProvider.logRecordBuilder()

var attributes: [String: AttributeValue] = [:]
attributes["TestAttributeA"] = AttributeValue("TestAttributeValueA")
attributes["TestAttributeB"] = AttributeValue("TestAttributeValueB")
attributes["TestAttributeC"] = AttributeValue("TestAttributeValueC")

logRecordBuilder = logRecordBuilder.setAttributes(attributes)
logRecordBuilder = logRecordBuilder.setBody("LogBody")
logRecordBuilder = logRecordBuilder.setObservedTimestamp(Date.now)
logRecordBuilder = logRecordBuilder.setSeverity(Severity.debug3)

logRecordBuilder.emit()


var eventBuilder = eventProvider.eventBuilder(name: "asdf")
eventBuilder = eventBuilder.setAttributes(attributes)
eventBuilder = eventBuilder.setBody("LogBody")
eventBuilder = eventBuilder.setObservedTimestamp(Date.now)
eventBuilder = eventBuilder.setSeverity(Severity.debug3)

eventBuilder.emit()
```